# Time complexity of recursive function that calls two halves floor(x / 2) and ceil(x / 2)

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, brute-force

I have a function `f(x)` that calls `f(x / 2)` if `x` is even and calls both `f((x + 1) / 2)` and `f((x - 1) / 2)` if `x` is odd. Note that `f(1) = constant` and we don't recurse further than `f(1)`. (So, it can be said that `f(1)` is the base condition.)

If I memoize `f(x)`, what will be the time complexity of computing `f(x)`? Will it be `O(2 ^ n)` because two functions are called at every level, or will it improve because of memoization?

I tried some cases by hand, and it seems that the complexity is no more than `O(log n)` and only two new functions are called at every level of recursion. (If I don't memoize, it does seem to be `O(2 ^ n)`)

I'd be glad if someone could help me with the complexity. Thanks!

Comment: You can prove that starting from `f(x)`, in the full recursion you only ever end up calling `f` with arguments of the form `floor(x / 2^k)` and `ceil(x / 2^k)`. (For example, `ceil(floor(x/2)/2)` will always be one of `ceil(x/4)` or `floor(x/4)`.) So yes, the complexity of the memoized recursion should indeed be `O(log n)`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider some number `x` written in binary as `x = 11001`.

If `x` is even then it's `lsb`(least significant bit) is `0` and we have `f(x) = f(x / 2)`.

If `x` is odd then it's `lsb` is `1` and depending on the second significant bit we will have two cases:

- second significant bit is `0` then `(x - 1) / 2` is even and `(x + 1) / 2` is odd.
- second significant bit is `1` then `(x - 1) / 2` is odd and `(x + 1) / 2` is even.

In both cases we will have `f(x) = f(someEvenNumber) + f(someOddNumber)`.

This means any bit in the number will cost either `1` operation if this bit is not set, and `1` operation + `f(y)` where `y` is `< x / 2)`. The number of these bits is at most `log (x)` so total complexity will be `2 * log(x)` which is same as `log (x)`.